# how to assign all elements of 2d vector same value after declaration

Tags: c++

how to assign all elements of 2d vector same value after declaration.

```
int largestIsland(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
     
        int res=0;
        bool flag=true;
        int n=grid.size();
        vector<vector<bool>> visited(n,vector<bool>(n,false));
        for(int i=0;i<grid.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<grid[i].size();j++){
                if(grid[i][j]==0){
                   flag=false;
                   grid[i][j]=1; 
                   res=max(res,dfs(grid,visited,i,j,n)); 
                   grid[i][j]=0; 
                   visited {n,vector<bool>(n,false)}; 
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag) return n*n;
        return res;
    }
    int dfs(vector<vector<int>>& grid,vector<vector<bool>>& visited,int i,int j,int n){
        if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=n || j>=n) return 0;
        if(visited[i][j] || grid[i][j]==0) return 0;
        visited[i][j]=true;
        int l=dfs(grid,visited,i,j-1,n);
        int r=dfs(grid,visited,i,j+1,n);
        int t=dfs(grid,visited,i-1,j,n);
        int d=dfs(grid,visited,i+1,j,n);
        return l+r+t+d+1;
    }
};
```

Comment: You want to reset all the values to false?

Answer (score -2):

You can try this out:

```
vector<vector<int>> vect('SIZE', vector<int>('SIZE',0));
```

Comment: No, its declaration I am talking about meanwhile in the code for that I have found answer  -                        
visited.assign(n,vector<bool>(n,false));